How to get column values from SpreadsheetColumn from SpaceSpreadsheet.columns?
I can get column name from SpreadsheetColumn but how to get column values from SpreadsheetColumn? I have enclosed python code and screen shot. Request any one help.
Thanks
Screenshot link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i4KuEDs4Z--V0bva76idwkREAcfTe7Ru
Code:
import bpy

def find_spreadsheet_space():
    # Find 3D_View window and its scren space
    area = None
    for a in bpy.data.window_managers[0].windows[0].screen.areas:
        if a.type == "SPREADSHEET":
            area = a
            break
    return area.spaces[0] if area else bpy.context.space_data

s_sheet = find_spreadsheet_space()

print(s_sheet) # SpaceSpreadsheet 

collist = s_sheet.columns 
print(collist)   # column collection

print( s_sheet.columns.items() ) # tupple 


for col in s_sheet.columns.items():
    print(col[1])                      # Getting SpreadsheetColumn
    print(col[1].id)                   # Getting SpreadsheetColumnID
    print(col[1].id.name)              # etting SpreadsheetColumnID name


#Result:

#<bpy_collection[1], SpaceSpreadsheet.columns>
#[(0, bpy.data.screens['Scripting']...SpreadsheetColumn)]
#<bpy_struct, SpreadsheetColumn at 0x00000137C70A1C80>
#<bpy_struct, SpreadsheetColumnID at 0x00000137C755D920>
#position


# How I can get column name from SpreadsheetColumn 
# but how to get column values from SpreadsheetColumn


Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See How to upload an image to a post? or GIF
